# Почему нельзя сохраннять Activity в статическом объекте, при пересоздании

Tags: android

На официальном сайте *Android*'a имеется [статья](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html), где рекомендуется сохранять объемные объекты (а точнее их ссылки) из`Activity`, на время пересоздания, в фрагменте (который не имеет UI и не пересоздается).

Но я все же не могу понять: а почему нельзя использовать для тех же целей синглтоны? Получить его можно из любого экземпляра `Activity` (ссылки он, вроде как, тоже не теряет :)), так в чем же проблемы и почему это не является самым простым способом сохранения?

Comment: синглтон будет удерживать ссылки и провоцировать утечки памяти (не давать активити, которые уже закрыты уничтожить их сборщику мусора), как минимум. И вообще синглтон объявлен антипатерном в ООП, приходится думать, как решать проблемы без него.

Comment: @pavlofff а фрагмент не будет удерживать ссылки?

Comment: @rjhdby фрагмент часть активити, а не внешний статик-объект и будет уничтожен вместе с ней. Вообще все проблемы из-за пересоздания при повороте и есть несколько способов решить это, ретейн-фрагмент удобен в ряде использований. но не единственное решение.

Comment: @pavlofff а если нам не нужно уничтожать данные при уничтожении конкретного активити?

Comment: @rjhdby если не нужно, то не уничтожайте. Сохраняйте их на внешние хранилища (файл, БД, преференсы). Не надо мешать в кучу мух и котлет, здесь речь идет о восстановлении после пересоздания, а не сохранении - синглтон в любом случае не удачное решение для долговременного хранения данных.

Comment: схожий [вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/488660/177345)

Comment: @pavlofff, не знал, что синглтон — антипаттерн. Но все же, почему он должен удерживать ссылку на активность? Я имею ввиду передавать объекты, которые не привязаны к контексту (БД менеджеры, объекты с информацией и т.д.).

Comment: @RostislavDugin не обязательно будет, но может. За этим надо следить очень внимательно, если решится использовать. У синглтона есть и другие существенные недостатки, которые делают его не лучшим кандидатом на буфер и даже [вовсе антипаттерном](http://pro-prof.com/archives/1546)(смотрите недостатки)

Comment: @pavlofff, благодарю. Посмотрите еще комментарий под ответ Бармалея, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно в *Singleton*, с одной поправкой: надо использовать естественный синглтон Android'а класс `Application`, который в любом месте можно получить через `getApplication()`. Технически надо создать собственный класс:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
   private MyData myData;
   private static MyApplication me;

   public MyApplication() {
      me=this;
   }

   public static MyApplication getApplication() {
      return me;
   }
   public MyData getMyData() {
      return myData;
   }
}
```

Теперь в любом месте можно вызвать:

```
MyApplication.getApplication().getMyData();
```

или через контекст (если не нравится)

```
((MyApplication )context.getApplication()).getMyData();
```

P.S. Надо не забыть задекларировать `MyApplication` в манифесте.

Comment: Только что, по ссылке показанной @pavloff, я прочитал, что, после закрытия приложения из-за нехватки памяти, будет восстанавливаться только верхняя `Activity` и `Application`, соответственно, обычный `Singleton` — уже будет другим. Вы поэтому рекомендуете использовать `Application` в качестве синглтона или есть другие причины? И можете подсказать, где можно получить информацию на тему восстановления приложения в случае его закрытия, про поведение объектов в `Android` и т.д.?

Comment: @RostislavDugin по интересующим вас вопросам можно почитать практически в любой качественной литературе по разработке под Android (книгах). Статьи в интернете как правило не дают полной информации, за исключением пожалуй https://developer.android.com/ - здесь собрано ВСЕ, что нужно знать андроид-разработчику.

Comment: @pavlofff, то есть можно спокойно брать и методично штудировать весь сайт?

Comment: @RostislavDugin Если с английским хорошо, то да. если плохо, то сначала лучше на русском почитать, например, книгу по андроид разработке  Брайна Харди, второе издание. В соответствующем разделе на форуме 4pda есть много хорошей литературы на последних страницах 20 - 30 где то.

Comment: @pavlofff, с английским, пока что, плоховато, но на android.developer довольно не сложно пишут (ну или я таких статей не видел).

Answer (score 3):

Можно и в `Singleton` сохранять. Они имеют ввиду хранить данные, которые нужны только конкретной активити. Если использовать `Singleton`, то вам придется следить, чтобы эти данные удалялись по уничтожению данной активити. А если использовать retain fragment то этого делать не надо будет.

Comment: Вот Вы сейчас что-то совсем неправильное написали. Зачем мне `Singleton` для хранения данных в конкретной `Activity`, если я могу хранить их прямо в этой `Activity`? И, если Вы о захвате `Activity` `Fragment`'ом, он может делать абсолютно тоже самое.

Comment: Тогда непонятно какой вопрос вы задаете. Я вам объяснил в каком случае гугл рекомендует хранить данные в фрагменте.Если данные хранить в активити, то при перевороте они уничтожаться(если данные не сериализуемые и не парселейбел). для таких целей и хранят во фрагменте или в синглетоне. Остальное уже выше описано. В общем вы либо некорректно задали вопрос либо не совсем поняли что я вам написал

Comment: @pavel163 Вообще, для сохранения состояния используется `onSaveInstanceState()`\`onRestoreInstanceState()`  и упаковка в `Bundle` в самой активити, а вот если в бандл упаковать нельзя, то тогда уже ретэйн-фрагмент.

Comment: @pavlofff ну я написал про это в комментарии. Не писал это в ответе, т.к. это не входило в вопрос. Вопрос был конкретным про retain fragment и singleton)))