# Замена Application для библиотеки

Tags: android, android-library

Написал библиотеку, тестировал все в соседнем модуле того же проекта. Однако, при сборке `.arr` и добавлении в другой проект, столкнулся с проблемой, что `Application` библиотеки равен `null`! Обшарил просторы интернета и везде писали о том, что нельзя использовать `Application` в библиотеках.

В силу того, что моя библиотека строиться на едином экземпляре одного объекта, мне нужен какой-то однозначно статический класс, который будет "раздавать" синглтоны и переживет все на свете. В моем случае — это был `Application`. Он создавал единственный экземпляр объекта и давал его всей библиотеке (не прибегая к статическим переменным, что очень хорошо).

Теперь возник вопрос: а что можно использовать как замену `Application`? Обязательным условием является существование на протяжении всей жизни приложения без пересоздания и потери ссылок на объекты внутри себя.

---

Я стараюсь избегать статических синглтонов, которые создают себя через `.getInstance()` исходя из вот этого вопроса — [Singleton в Android - зло?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/488660/singleton-%D0%B2-android-%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%BE)

Comment: Наверное нужно построить архитектуру без синглтона. На шине данных, классических коммуникациях Android или с постоянным промежуточным хранилищем (преференсы или БД) в зависимости от решаемых библиотекой задач. Мне как то ни разу не приходилось использовать синглтон ( в большинстве изученных мной библиотек (во всех даже скорее) этот паттерн тоже не используется