# SQLite Singleton статика и смерть

Tags: android, sqlite, context, singleton

Доброго. Тема затёртая вроде бы, но всё же. Изучил данную тему [Singleton в Android - зло?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/488660/singleton-%D0%B2-android-%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%BE)
Сделал класс для работы с БД (обычный синглтон):

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String TAG = DBHelper.class.getName();

private static DBHelper mDbInstance = null;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "tvbusplayer";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public static synchronized DBHelper getInstance(Context context) {

    if (mDbInstance == null) {
        mDbInstance = new DBHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
    }

    return mDbInstance;
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    super.close();

    mDbInstance.close();
}

private DBHelper(Context context) {
       super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}}
```

Первый вызов getInstance делаю из MainActivity,и, следуя ответу из темы по ссылке, передаю контекст приложения:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mDb = DBHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
```

Правильно ли я понимаю:

1. никаких неявных ссылок на activity нет
2. благодаря getApplicationContext() экземпляр будет жить пока не умрёт приложение ?
3. если я использовал getApplicationContext() мне нет нужды создавать приватную переменную в потомке класса Application ?