# Singleton. приватная переменная в потомке класса Application

Tags: java, android, singleton

В одном из ответов на форуме есть такие слова:

*Лучше создать приватную переменную в потомке класса Application со ссылкой на экземпляр вместо приватной статической в самом классе сиглтона, если это возможно.*

Я запутался, не могу понять разницу, покажите пожалуйста код, где всё сделано по этой рекомендации и код, где переменная в самом классе.

Ну вот переменная в самом классе, выглядит так:

```
public class Singleton { 
 private static Singleton instance; 

 private Singleton (){} 

 public static Singleton getInstance(){ 
  if (null == instance){ 
   instance = new Singleton(); 
  } 
  return instance; 
 } 
}
```

Переменная в подклассе `Application` как выглядит не пойму..Скорее потому, что я не понимаю в чем будет выгода, если выполнить эту рекомендацию.

Принятый ответ в этом вопросе и является темой моего вопроса
[Singleton в Android - зло?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/488660)

Comment: Возможно, при возобновлении работы приложения берётся тот же экземпляр `Application`, а вот остальные классы инициализируются заново. Поэтому "настоящий" синглтон должен быть в `Application`. Но это только догадка.

Comment: выгода в том, что наследник класса Application - естественный синглтон анроид-приложения. он гарантировано в одном экземпляре, существует, пока существует приложение и будет уничтожен вместе с приложением. "самодельный" синглтон ничего из этого не может грантировать в системе андроид. Просто создаете переменную, геттер/сеттер в наследнике Application и все. самого наследника объявляете в манифесте

Comment: Я приложил ссылку на вопрос, речь о принятом ответе

Comment: @pavloff, да я про это читал, но во-первых не пойму в каком случае приведенный мною вариант может подвести в системе андроид, если исключить проблему с многопоточностью. И во-вторых как всё-таки будет выглядеть синглтон с static переменной в потомке классе Application ? всё то же самое только дополнительно ссылка на экземпляр в наследнике  Application? Мне нужно увидеть этот код,  а то уже куча реализаций разом в голове и их отличия слились в кашу. Популярные статьи  и вопросы по данной тематике  я уже прочел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application - базовый класс для хранения глобального состояния приложения. Использовать можно например так (нужно добавить android:name=".MyApplication" в раздел  файла AndroidManifest.xml):

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private String mName;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        setName("Application instance is maintaining global application state");
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        mName = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MyApplication myApplication = (MyApplication)getApplication();
        String s = myApplication.getName();
        Log.d("TAG", s);
        myApplication.setName("tester");
        Log.d("TAG", myApplication.getName());
    }
}
```

Однако гугл рекомендует использовать Singleton:

> Note: There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most
>   situations, static singletons can provide the same functionality in a
>   more modular way. If your singleton needs a global context (for
>   example to register broadcast receivers), include
>   Context.getApplicationContext() as a Context argument when invoking
>   your singleton's getInstance() method.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application