# Как вытащить данные из сессии для других активностей

Tags: java, android

```
 //This method will clear the sharedpreference
    //It will be called on logout
    public void logout() {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences().edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.apply();
    }
```

Comment: Объявите методы и переменные статикой

Comment: Синглтоны надо уметь готовить в Андроид, ваш вариант -- прямой путь к утечкам памяти: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/488660/singleton-%D0%B2-android-%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%BE/488737#488737

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приведу пример своей реализации. Чать класс Utils:

```
class Utils {
    public static SharedPreferences.Editor getSharedPrefEditor(Context context) {
        return context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    }

    public static String getCurrentUserRole(Context context) {
        return getSharedPref(context).getString(User.ROLE, "");
    }

    public static String getCurrentUserPhone(Context context) {
        return getSharedPref(context).getString(User.PHONE, null);
    }
}
```

Код на добавление:

```
    SharedPreferences.Editor sharedPrefEditor = Utils.getSharedPrefEditor(this);
    sharedPrefEditor.putString(User.ROLE, user.getRole());
    sharedPrefEditor.putString(User.USER_ID, firebaseUser.getUid());
    sharedPrefEditor.putString(User.USER_NAME, user.getName());
    sharedPrefEditor.putString(User.USER_EMAIL, user.getEmail());
    sharedPrefEditor.putString(User.USER_AVATAR, user.getAvatarUrl());
    sharedPrefEditor.putString(User.PHONE, user.getPhone());
    sharedPrefEditor.apply();
```

Comment: ни вижу никакой проблемы. Т.к. методы статические, вы можете из любого участка кода передав контекст получить нужную вам переменную. И уже затем по своему усмотрению установить ее в TextView или вывести в консоль

Comment: ооо.. почитайте учебники. Рано вам проекты писать.

Comment: Каких авторов  учебники посоветуешь ?Кто нибудь ешё может показать полный пример запроса вместе с listview Мне нужно просто выташить данные из другой таблицы ...