# Проблема с сохранением данных в sharedpreference android

Tags: android

У меня в приложении мне нужно сохранить access_token который я получаю в ответе с сервера. Для дальнейшей работы мне нужно сохранить этот токен и потом его вставить в хедер в интерфейсе, вот код интерфейса:

```
@Headers({"Content-type: application/json"})
    @GET("/v1/message/list")
    Call<ListOfMess> getInMess(@Header("Authorization") String token, @Query("type") int type, @Query("offset") int offset);
```

где access_token это переменная string которую я ввожу вручную. А вот что-бы во время регистрации программа сохраняла этот токен и вставляла самостоятельно на место этой переменной я использую sharedpreferences.

---

Вставил этот вариант в том месте где я получаю из тела ответа токен:

```
String token = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getAccess_token();
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(SP_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
preferences.edit().putString(Constants.SP_ACCESS_TOKEN, token).apply();
```

---

Фрагмент класса там где я пытаюсь вставить токен:

```
 public void received() {
            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://сервер/")
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();


            String access_token = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1MzMwNDQzMzMsInVzZXJfaWQiOjk1MzM5NjEsImlzcyI6ImFwaS5qb2Itc2VydmVyLm5ldCJ9.z17w6N_66yHR7MLXtz8DijCaI5Gh52BpUYnIwvkvd_k";
            final APIService mAPIService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
            mAPIService.getInMess("Bearer "+access_token,0, 1).enqueue(new Callback<ListOfMess>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ListOfMess> call, @NonNull Response<ListOfMess> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ListOfMess> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

                }
            });
        }


        /*private String getTokenFromShared(){
            return getSharedPreferences(Constants.SP_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).getString(Constants.SP_ACCESS_TOKEN, "");
        }*/
```

в нем есть строковая переменная которую я потом вставляю в хедер.

---

но вот проблема у меня в том что я не могу получить этот токен в другом активити, у меня была мысль просто использовать  intent.putExtra... что-бы просто кидать этот токен на нужный мне экран, но это слишком по-моему костыльно и не очень красиво будет работать. Мой вопрос заключается в том как сохранить данные в sharedpreferences в одном активити а потом эти-же данные получить в любой другой активити.

Надеюсь я объяснил не очень путано и мне кто-то поможет.

Comment: буквально миниуту назад я описывал реализаю такого класс в другом вопрос) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/862432/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9

Comment: спасибо не заметил походу))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сохраняем токен:

```
private fun saveToken(token: Token) {
        val preferences = getSharedPreferences(SP_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE)
        preferences.edit().apply {
            putString(SP_ACCESS_TOKEN, token.accessToken)
            putString(SP_TYPE, token.type)
            putLong(SP_EXPIRES_IN, token.expiresIn)
            putString(SP_REFRESH_TOKEN, token.refreshToken)
        }.apply()
    }
```

Получаем токен в любой активити:

```
private fun getTokenFromShared(): String { 
        return getSharedPreferences(SP_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).getString(SP_ACCESS_TOKEN, "")
    }
```

Константы:

```
const val SP_NAME = "Config"
const val SP_ACCESS_TOKEN = "accessToken"
const val SP_TYPE = "type"
const val SP_EXPIRES_IN = "expiresIn"
const val SP_REFRESH_TOKEN = "refreshToken"
```

**UPDATE for Java:**

```
  private void saveToken(String token) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(SP_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        preferences.edit().putString(SP_ACCESS_TOKEN, token).apply();
    }

    private String getTokenFromShared(){
        return getSharedPreferences(SP_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).getString(SP_ACCESS_TOKEN, "");
    }
```

и можно создать отдельный Constants класс:

```
public class Constants {
    static final String SP_NAME = "Config";
    static final String SP_ACCESS_TOKEN = "accessToken";
}
```

и те методы просто импортировать константы (IDE предложит сама)

Comment: несколько вопросов по поводу вашего ответа, во-первых если я правильно понял, функция savetoken должна быть инициализирована в mainactivity, и дальше мы просто к ней обращаемся. Дальше константы мы в начале класса mainactivity обозначаем или где-то в другом месте? и как вставить вытащенный токен в вашем ответе?

Comment: 1. функцию saveToken используйте там, где нужно сохранить токен (там где вы его получили с сервера - модель Token или просто стринга)
2. Константы можно объявить где вам удобно (я например выношу в отдельный файл, общий для всего проекта)
3. метод getTokenFromShared() возвращает строку (токен из шаредов), которую вы можете использовать по назначению

Comment: а как вы выносите все переменные?? я просто за такое первый раз слышу)) я вот пытаюсь объявить константы, и студия не может понять что это такое. функция тоже вообще не хочет инициализироваться.

Comment: возможно потому что у Вас проект на Java) а я привел пример на Kotlin)
Могу попробовать перевести на Java)
Выношу не переменный, а константы

Comment: я сижу думаю почему не могу ничего инициализировать и вызвать)))))))) если метод работает то я был бы очень благодарен если бы вы мне его перевели на java так как с kotlin я не знаком сильно))

Comment: Добавил, логика та же..только в метод saveToken можно передать сразу строку токена

Comment: то есть теперь можно насколько я понял прописать константы и метод в одном классе и вызвать все это в другом? getSharedPreferences например не находит, его повторно нужно объявлять?

Comment: getSharedPreferences может не находить только по одной причине - вызывается за пределами контекста (его нужно вызывать на контексте - например в активити)

Comment: Вы можете все константы вынести в отдельный класс. А методы вызывать в нужных вам активити

Comment: сейчас попробую сделать так как вы говорите, так как простая вставка метода видимо не будет так просто работать))

Comment: ну вот я добавил класс с переменными (прикольная штука кстати я если честно и не знал про нее) но функция все равно не видится, я ее вызываю за пределами onViewCreated класса, где находятся пределы контекста, мне вообще нужно закинуть этот токен из одной активити в другую, и присвоить ей string, пробовал так: String access_token = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SP_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).getString(Constants.SP_ACCESS_TOKEN, ""); но почему-то не помогло)) опять что-то пропускаю походу?

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "функция все равно не видится" ??
И не пишите никогда access_token, используйте CamelCase (т.е. accessToken)

Comment: сейчас дополню вопрос с учетом вашего ответа.