# Как сохранять состояние view и presenter

Tags: java, android, mvp

Как сохранить presenter при смене конфигурации телефона, например при повороте? Прочитал много способов, но так и не понял, какой лучше всего использовать. Знаю про Loader и Dagger, но не понял, как в нем сохранить presenter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача в том чтобы презентер пережил разрушение вью(в нашем случае `Activity` или `Fragment`). Сделать это можно различными способами, можно добавить презентер в граф дагера, объявив его `@Singleton`'ом, чтобы понять как это сделать нужно ближе познакомится с дагером, или [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) использовать. Можно просто объявить [Singleton](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/488660/singleton-%D0%B2-android-%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%BE), есть мнение что это не плохое решение.