# Получить доступ к классу из другого Activity

Tags: android, activity, bluetooth

Доброго времени суток.

Есть MainActivity, в нем происходит поиск и сопряжение к Bluetooth устройству.

Есть отдельный класс BluetoothConnectionService, в котором происходит соединение и управление устройством. Соединение происходит в MainActivity, после чего вызывается DeviceControlActivity в котором уже должно происходить управление устройством: прием/передача данных и тд. с использованием того же BluetoothConnectionService. Проблема в том, что не получается получить доступ к классу из второго активити. Первичная инициализация BluetoothConnectionService происходит в MainActivity:

```
mBluetoothConnection = new BluetoothConnectionService(MainActivity.this);
```

Инициализация в DeviceControlActivity не работает:

```
mBluetoothConnection = new BluetoothConnectionService(this);
// или
mBluetoothConnection = new BluetoothConnectionService(DeviceControlActivity.this);
```

Ошибок нет, просто происходит игнор mBluetoothConnection.

Управление устройством удалось реализовать через LocalBroadcastManager, который отправляет Intent'ы из второго активити в первое, а там уже они обрабатываются BluetoothConnectionService, но понимаю что можно обойтись без этого посредника и работать с методами напрямую. Пробовал передать объект в активити через Intent.putExtra() и Serializable - не прокатило (мб не так сделал).

Заранее прошу прощения если я затупил на чем-нибудь простом, т.к. еще новичок. Благодарю.

Часть кода BluetoothConnectionService:

```
public class BluetoothConnectionService {

public static final String ACTION_SOCKET_NOT_CLOSED = "Socket connection failed";
public static final String ACTION_SUCCESS           = "Socket connection successful";
public static final String ACTION_INCOMING_DATA     = "Got input data from buffer";

private static final String TAG = "BTCS";

private static UUID USER_UUID = null;

Context mContext;

private final BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private ConnectThread connectThread;
private ConnectedThread connectedThread;

public BluetoothConnectionService(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
}
// Дальше идет код для создания сокета и обмена данными
```

Comment: Самый просто способ, создать Singleton BluetoothManager.

Comment: Не называйте свои классы *Service, если они не являются действительно сервисами в понятиях системы Андроид. Это очень путает. Вам нужен только один экземпляр BluetoothConnectionService, вариант 2 отсюда думаю подойдет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/488737/184031

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, благодарю, попробую реализовать